# Updating drag object state in React breaks application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a bit specific. I've been trying to fix this two days in a row without any success and I can feel my brain cells are melting already, so I figured it's best to just ask for help. Okay, so I'm building a search algorithms visualizer:

[image]

My Grid component initalizes a matrix that I iterate to create the grid layout seen above, returning a Node component (below) for every node in the matrix. My idea is that the user should be able to click and drag both the `start` and `end` nodes and drop them in any cell they want. For that I'm using the onDragStart and onDragEnter events. Now the tricky part. To make that, I'm:

1. Tracking which node (either 'start' or 'end') the user is dragging;
2. Keeping track of the last cell the node was in with the 'onDragStart' event;
3. Using the 'onDragEnter' event I track everytime the node is hovering above what cell;
4. Everytime the 'onDragEnter' event fires, the node is appended to the corresponding cell;
5. Once all that is done, I use the `last_cell_id` and the `new_cell_id` to update the corresponding nodes from the matrix;
6. Lastly, I need to update the `start/end` node row and column states in my Grid component, to later pass down into the dijkstra function.

When I try to update said state it crashes. This is my Node component so far:

```
const Node = ({ nodeMatrix, stateHandling, dragStateHandling, row, col, isStart, isEnd }) => {

    const { setStartNodeRow, setStartNodeCol, setEndNodeRow, setEndNodeCol } = stateHandling;
    const { draggedItem, setDraggedItem } = dragStateHandling;

    //Just handling the 'start' node for now
    const handleDragStart = (e) => {
        const isStartNode = e.target.classList.contains('start');

        const startNode = document.querySelector('.start');
        //const endNode = document.querySelector('.end');
        
        const [prevStartParentNodeRow, prevStartParentNodeCol] = startNode.parentElement.id.match(/\d+/g);
        //const [prevEndParentNodeRow, prevEndParentNodeCol] = endNode.parentElement.id.match(/\d+/g);

        if(isStartNode) {
            setDraggedItem('start');
            //Sets the data for the drag object to be retrieved later and
            //used to update the corresponding node in the matrix;
            e.dataTransfer.setData('prevNodeId', `node-${prevStartParentNodeRow}-${prevStartParentNodeCol}`);

        } else {
            setDraggedItem('end');
            //e.dataTransfer.setData('prevNodeId', `node-${prevEndParentNodeRow}-${prevEndParentNodeCol}`)
        }
    };

    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
        const startNode = document.querySelector('.start');
        const endNode = document.querySelector('.end');

        //This check avoids the 'start' and 'end' divs and 
        //always selects the parent cell;
        const newParent = e.target.id ? e.target : e.target.parentElement.id ? e.target.parentElement : e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        const hoveringOver = newParent.id;

        //Retrieves the data set in 'handleDragStart' from the drag object to use as keys
        //to update the previous 'start' node in the grid;
        const [prevNodeRow, prevNodeCol] = e.dataTransfer.getData('prevNodeId').match(/\d+/g);

        //Gets the id of the cell we're currently hovering over to update
        //the new 'start' node in the grid;
        const [newRow, newCol] = hoveringOver.match(/\d+/g);

        if(draggedItem === 'start') {
            //All this methods work as intended,
            //the previous 'start' node gets updated alongside the new one
            //in the nodesMatrix;
            newParent.appendChild(startNode);            
            nodeMatrix[prevNodeRow][prevNodeCol].isStart = false;
            nodeMatrix[newRow][newCol].isStart = true;

            //↓ If uncommented, this throws the following error
            //↓ as soon as we drag the start node:
            //(DOMException: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node);

            /*
            setStartNodeRow(parseInt(newRow));
            setStartNodeCol(parseInt(newCol));
            */

        };
        
        if(draggedItem === 'end') {
            newParent.appendChild(endNode);
            nodeMatrix[prevNodeRow][prevNodeCol].isEnd = false;
            nodeMatrix[newRow][newCol].isEnd = true;

            /*
            setEndNodeRow(parseInt(newRow));
            setEndNodeCol(parseInt(newCol));
            */
        };
};

    return (
        <div id={`node-${ row }-${ col }`} onDragEnter={handleDragEnter} className={...} >
            { isStart && 
            <div onDragStart={handleDragStart} draggable={true} className={...} >
            <i className={...}/>
            </div>
            }
            { isEnd && 
            <div onDragStart={handleDragStart} draggable={true} className={...} >
            <i className={...}/>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Node
```

I think I get why updating the state is causing a crash, but after this many hours I'm kind of just tunnel thinking and can't see any solutions. I guess this post is long enough as it is so I have made a codesandbox if someone wants to check it out for any reason: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-https-n1mrk9

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something which should be avoided in react. And it is changing DOM outside of react.

What is happening - React uses something called virtual DOM and based on changes on virtual DOM it updates real DOM.
But you are directly appending elements into real DOM (by calling `newParent.appendChild`). It is where react is confused because DOM and VDOM do not match.

You should find a way how to implement this behaviour purely by react code.
Maybe get inspired here: https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/easy-drag-and-drop-in-react-22778b30ba37